# Understand end of transmission of email message in SMTP

Tags: c#, email, smtp, handshake

I have a log for a simple SMTP transaction. (Its a bit long so access it [here](https://gist.github.com/deostroll/b9ba32908750a3a6f96a)). It shows the exchange of low-level handshakes such as `HELO`, `MAIL`, etc.

When the server which is supposed to receive an email is ready to accept email data, it send the following (line 12 in the log):

```
RawSmtp Information: 0 : << 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
```

However, the end of transmission is a bit confusing (lines 74/75):

```
RawSmtp Information: 0 : >> cannot foresee
RawSmtp Information: 0 : >> 
RawSmtp Information: 0 : << 250 OK
```

which when viewed in notepad looks like:

[image]

The code however is simply written like this:

```
                            WriteResponse(writer, "354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>");
                            string line;
                            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null && line != ".")
                            {
                                //do stuff
                            }
```

Is that standard? I mean sending something like `<CRLF>.<CRLF>` and only checking for the dot (`.`)...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is checking for a whole line with just a `.` in it. 
This is the standard technique for indicating the end of a DATA section. See [here](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/smtp-commands-reference.htm).

Also, as @jstedfast points out, the `StreamReader.ReadLine()` method removes the `"\r\n"` end-of-line sequence from the strings that it returns, so in that case, the resulting string will be `"."`

Comment: Just to clarify your answer a bit: the StreamReader.ReadLine() method removes the `"\r\n"` end-of-line sequence from the strings that it returns, so in that case, the resulting string will be `"."`.